# Qgis Sentinel 2 black images

Tags: qgis

I am working with Sentinel 2 bands in Qgis 2.18. When I load them to Qgis' TOC, they appear in black and in the layers panel they do not display the minimum and maximum number of pixels. I would like to solve this problem.

Comment: Hello Dan, I think we are going to need more information about your issue to help you out. What have you tried already? Screenshots and/or examples are also handy.

Comment: Hello Kingfisher, apologies for my English and my poor explanation. I am calculating different indexes (NDVI, EVI, SAVI) using the corresponding Sentinel bands. When I loaded them to the TOC of Qgis I saw the pixels of the area of interest distinguishing forests, bushes, lakes, hills, etc. But now I can not distinguish anything, the image is black as if it were a single pixel. I guess it's a Qgis configuration problem, but I can not solve it.